# route is not working in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ejs

[campground data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwsLm.png) i m working on this web app from a course where i m using mongodb ,the database is created (named as "campit") and collection is named as campground(but mongo has named it campgrounds as usual) .the collection consist of name and image. **a route (namely "/create") is not working**,
**by going to url "localhost:3000/create.ejs" its showing** Cannot GET /index.ejs
here is my code,this is **app.js** file

```
var express=require("express");
var app=express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/campit");
var campgroundSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
name:String,
image:String
});
app.get("/create",function(req,res){
campground.find({},function(err,campground){
  if(err){
    console.log(err)
  }
  else{
    console.log("successfully shown");
    res.render("index.ejs",{campgrounds:campground})
  }
});
app.listen("3000",function(){
  console.log("listening from server 3000");
});
```

this is  **index.ejs** file,which is supposed to show

```
    <div class="container">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <% campgrounds.forEach(function(camp){ %>
      <div class="col col-lg-4 img-thumbnail">
        <img class="but" height="75%" width="100%" src="<%=camp.image%>" alt="image">
        <div class="text-center">
          <h6><%= camp.name %> </h6>
          <button class="btn btn-outline-info " type="button" name="more info"> more info</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% }); %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

when i m going to **/create** route it shows that **campgrounds.forEach is not a function** error......whole code is same, something is wrong with rendering variable..... and i m sure that campgrounds contain data.
**EDIT CLOSE**

any kind of help will be highly appriciated.
**thank you.....**

Comment: Your route is not `/create.ejs`. It is `/create`.

Comment: Try adding folder_name/index.ejs in res.render method.
And also correct the route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this url **localhost:3000/create** instead of **localhost:3000/create.ejs** :)

In your Javascript file, you wrote **app.get('/create')**. **create.ejs** its just the name of your template. The path of your route and the name of your template doesn't need to be the same.

Comment: No problem :) Don't forget to mark this topic as resolve!

Comment: What does **campgrounds** contains? Could you console.log it and show the result please?

Answer (score 1):

You are hitting wrong url. As you can see in you code.

```
app.get("/create", function(req,res){
    campground.find({},function(err,campground){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
        else{
            console.log("successfully shown");
            res.render("index.ejs",{campgrounds:campground})
        }
    }
});
```

Route you should be using is **/create** and not **/create.ejs**. index.ejs is the template rendered when you visit **/create** route

Comment: I am unable to see campground defined in you code. Basically it should be defined as var campground =  mongoose.model('campground',campgroundSchema);. Have you done that?

Comment: i forget to add it on my EDIT but that line is present in my code,still nothing happen. when i m console.log the campground it shows some crazy json type data and when i m console.log the campgrounds it did not recognise it .......

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
var router = express.Router();
router.route('/create')
    .get(function(req,res){
 campground.find({},function(err,campground){
   if(err){
   console.log(err)
 }
else{
console.log("successfully shown");
res.render("index.ejs",{campgrounds:campground})
 }
});
  app.use('', router);
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget to set view engine, use code below after `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));`

**USE IT**

```
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
```